# How to get backup database in Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had a Google cloud account with 300 $ free, and I had created some website with it.

When my account spent all free money (the 300$) it was stopped service but I forgot to save backup databases of all my websites.

So please anyone can help me to get a backup database of my websites from Google Cloud? or show me how to get a link to download it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is unlikely that you get any information from Google Cloud now that you have depleted your resources unless you add a payment option.

Take into consideration that egress of information and network usage within Google Cloud also does have a cost.

If you happen to pay just to collect the data you had inside in any of the Google Cloud Platform services and you know an estimate of how much resources you need, you might be able to calculate the price in the [GCP calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)